# Asking for an estimate

Tags: word-usage

Let’s say I am to remodel my kitchen and need a price estimate from a store. What are my options expressing this in writing, in a more formal way? Quote of tender, tender offer, bid?

Comment: Are you looking for a word to describe the request for a price? Or are you asking how to write a request?

Comment: A word that sounds formal and is commenly used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

> I would appreciate it if you would provide me with a [**quotation**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quotation) for Model xxx, inclusive of all costs.

Or

> I would be grateful if you would let me have a quotation for Model xxx, inclusive of all costs.

**quotation**, *(informal)* quote: an estimate of costs  submitted by a contractor to a prospective client; tender.

Comment: Myself, I would regard a *quotation* as more reliable and binding than an *estimate*.

Comment: I guess an estimate wouldn't be binding at all, while a quotation or a quote of tender is a binding offer. Wonder why I got this question downvoted?

Comment: A quotation is an estimate, it is not binding by definition. If you are looking for a binding estimate you have to come to a formal written terms, sort of legal contract, with your counterpart. A quotation, or estimate are by definition a general idea, more or less accurate,  of costs.

Comment: @user70579 a quotation or quote is more reliable than an estimate insofar as it's a written statement. A more binding alternative to a quote "officially" would be a pro forma invoice http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_forma

Comment: @Josh61 Correct. A quotation is nowhere near as binding as an estimate. It just sounds more reliable because it's a written statement.

Comment: To my knowledge also an 'estimate' is a written statement, anyway, experience has taught us that effective real costs are always higher ( God knows why) than what previously estimated. That's why  more formal 'statement' is need.. If you are able to have it. :)

Comment: @Josh61 Check this out, Josh61 :-) http://www.estimate.info/article/5949/quotation_vs_estimate

Comment: Interesting, thanks! As stated in the link in the end it all comes down to having a 'written' list of costs correctly estimated. Nice issue :))

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you need an  [estimate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Estimate)

- A statement of the approximate cost of work to be done, such as a building project or car repairs.